# Generate model classes from Database for Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have VS Database project with schema and existing published Database.
Now i have internal routines to arrange some data in this database and i'm going to use Linq to SQL for this. Is it possible to auto-generate model classes from Database project or existing database? I've created mapping XML, but to use it i need to generate classes. Is there any automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial should help you: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs

You have to add add "linq to sql classes" which will generate you models.